# "go get" git error on all sources but golang.org

Tags: git, github, go

**go version go1.5.1 windows/amd64
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1**

I have been trying to get some Go libraries.
They are downloaded fine, when accessed on golang.org
but github.com or google.golang.org packages give an error.

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details
```

[image: go get gives an error when fetching from google.golang.org]

[image: go get gives no error when fetching from golang.org]

Comment: Don't use screen shots for text log/error messages. Images are not searchable or selecatable.

Comment: Git 1.9.5 is probably **way** to old. Or your git config is strange.

Comment: @DaveC I have attached a text description of the same error in the same concern. Hope you managed to notice.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the package from GOPATH and go get it again. Your package is modified and git is refusing to pull from upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

In case your branch is different than "master" you can confirm it with:

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: i'm not working inside a repo, but would just like to download the package using "go get". your command throws a fatal error about git repository.

Comment: @Carla is referring to the repository in the $GOPATH/src directory. When you `go get` the tooling is cloning a copy of the library into to your $GOPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody who might expirience the same error you could try.
`go get -v -u -x ${package name}`